# Drupal Commerce: commerce-order:email is empty in checkout completion rule

Tags: commerce

I'm new to Drupal Commerce and I'm developing a site with anonymous checkout.

It seems that when the "Send an order notification e-mail" rule kicks in (checkout completion rules) the commerce-order:mail is empty and the email is not sent.

I have already disabled "Create a new account for an anonymous order" and "Assign an anonymous order to a pre-existing user" rules and a breakpoint on rules_action_mail() function proves that $to (mail recipient) variable is empty.

I'm using paymill and a custom shipping method module.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.